# Vagrant & Puppet - Provisioning Failing

Tags: puppet, vagrant

I am taking my first Foray into using Vagrant + Puppet Provisioning scripts to improve my development workflow.

I am currently trying to set up a dev box for L4 development - and am using the https://github.com/paolooo/vagrant-lamp and https://github.com/paolooo/puppet-laravel.

Following the instructions:

Clone the LAMP box:

```
git clone git://github.com/paolooo/vagrant-lamp.git lamp
cd lamp
```

Add Puppet provisioning scripts:

```
git submodule add https://github.com/paolooo/puppet-laravel.git extras/modules/laravel
```

Then update submodules:

```
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

Great so far - easy stuff...

So now ready to run `vagrant up` - which seems to provision the VM fine, and boots it.

My problems however seem to start when the init.pp script runs. I am getting lots of 404's when the `apt-get <<package>>` runs.

My first thoughts were the network interface may be down -  but `mysql-client` download worked (i think) looking at the logs.

I have tried this on OSX and Windows machines.

Any help would be really appreciated - i dont want to fall at the first hurdle.

My Puppet Script:

```
# Default path
Exec { path => ['/usr/bin', '/bin', '/usr/sbin', '/sbin', '/usr/local/bin', '/usr/local/sbin', '/opt/local/bin'] }
exec { 'apt-get update':
  command => '/usr/bin/apt-get update --fix-missing',
  require => Exec['add php54 apt-repo']
}

# Configuration
if $db_name == '' { $db_name = 'development' }
if $db_location == '' { $db_location  = '/vagrant/db/development.sqlite' }
if $username == '' { $username = 'root' }
if $password == '' { $password = '123' }
if $host == '' { $host = 'localhost' }

# Setup

## PHP
include php54
class { 'php': version => latest, }

## APACHE2
include apache
class {'apache::mod::php': }

## PACKAGES
## 'vim','curl','unzip','git','php5-mysql','php5-sqlite','php5-mcrypt','php5-memcache',
## 'php5-suhosin','php5-xsl','php5-tidy','php5-dev','php5-pgsql','php5-odbc', 'php5-ldap','php5-xmlrpc','php5-intl','php5-fpm'
package { ['vim','curl','unzip','git','php5-mcrypt','php5-memcached']:
  ensure  => installed,
  require => Exec['apt-get update'],
}

package { ['php5-mysql','php5-sqlite']:
  ensure  => installed,
  require => Exec['apt-get update'],
}

include pear
include composer

### Apache
apache::vhost { $fqdn:
  priority  => '20',
  port => '80',
  docroot => $docroot,
  logroot => $docroot, # access_log and error_log
  configure_firewall  => false,
}
a2mod { 'rewrite': ensure => present }

## Ruby
class { "ruby": 
  gems_version => "latest"
}

## Nodejs
class { "nodejs": }

## PHP MODULES
php::module { ['curl', 'gd']:
  notify  => [ Service['httpd'], ],
}

## PEAR
pear::package { "PEAR": }
pear::package { "PHPUnit": 
  version     => "latest",
  repository  => "pear.phpunit.de",
  require     => Pear::Package["PEAR"],
}
pear::package { "Yaml": 
  version     => "latest",
  repository  => "pear.symfony.com",
  require     => Pear::Package["PEAR"]
}

## DB
### MySQL
class { 'mysql::server':
  config_hash => { 'root_password' => "${password}" }
}
class { 'mysql': }
mysql::db { "${db_name}":
  user  => "${username}",
  password  => "${password}",
  host  =>  "${host}",
  grant => ['all'],
  charset => 'utf8',
}

### PostgreSQL
class { 'postgresql':
  version => 'latest',
}
class { 'postgresql::server': }
postgresql::db { "${db_name}":
  owner => "${username}",
  password  => "${password}",
}

### SQLite Config
class { 'sqlite': }
define sqlite::db(
    $location   = '',
    $owner      = 'root',
    $group      = 0,
    $mode       = '755',
    $ensure     = present,
    $sqlite_cmd = 'sqlite3'
  ) {

      file { $safe_location:
        ensure  => $ensure,
        owner   => $owner,
        group   => $group,
        notify  => Exec['create_development_db']
      }

      exec { 'create_development_db':
        command     => "${sqlite_cmd} $db_location",
        path        => '/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin',
        refreshonly => true,
      }
  }

## phpmyadmin
class { 'phpmyadmin': }
```

My vagrant file:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant::Config.run do |config|
  # All Vagrant configuration is done here. The most common configuration
  # options are documented and commented below. For a complete reference,
  # please see the online documentation at vagrantup.com.

  # Every Vagrant virtual environment requires a box to build off of.
  config.vm.box = "precise32"

  # The url from where the 'config.vm.box' box will be fetched if it
  # doesn't already exist on the user's system.
  config.vm.box_url = "http://files.vagrantup.com/precise32.box"

  # Boot with a GUI so you can see the screen. (Default is headless)
  # config.vm.boot_mode = :gui

  # Assign this VM to a host-only network IP, allowing you to access it
  # via the IP. Host-only networks can talk to the host machine as well as
  # any other machines on the same network, but cannot be accessed (through this
  # network interface) by any external networks.
  config.vm.network :hostonly, "192.168.33.10"

  # Assign this VM to a bridged network, allowing you to connect directly to a
  # network using the host's network device. This makes the VM appear as another
  # physical device on your network.
  # config.vm.network :bridged

  # Forward a port from the guest to the host, which allows for outside
  # computers to access the VM, whereas host only networking does not.
  config.vm.forward_port 80, 8082

  # Share an additional folder to the guest VM. The first argument is
  # an identifier, the second is the path on the guest to mount the
  # folder, and the third is the path on the host to the actual folder.
  config.vm.share_folder "v-data", "/vagrant/db", "./db"
  config.vm.share_folder "v-web", "/vagrant/www", "c:\\www"

  # Enable provisioning with Puppet stand alone.  Puppet manifests
  # are contained in a directory path relative to this Vagrantfile.
  # You will need to create the manifests directory and a manifest in
  # the file base.pp in the manifests_path directory.
  #
  # An example Puppet manifest to provision the message of the day:
  #
  # # group { "puppet":
  # #   ensure => "present",
  # # }
  # #
  # # File { owner => 0, group => 0, mode => 0644 }
  # #
  # # file { '/etc/motd':
  # #   content => "Welcome to your Vagrant-built virtual machine!
  # #               Managed by Puppet.\n"
  # # }
  #
  config.vm.provision :puppet do |puppet|
    puppet.facter = {
      "fqdn"      => "dev.lamp.mysql",
      "hostname"  => "www",
      "docroot"   => "/vagrant/www",
      "host"      => 'localhost',
      "username"  => 'root',
      "password"  => '123',
      "db_name"   => "development",
      "db_location" => "/vagrant/db/development.sqlite"
    }
    puppet.manifests_path = "puppet/manifests"
    puppet.module_path = ["puppet/modules", "extras/modules"]
    puppet.manifest_file  = "init.pp"
  end

  # Enable provisioning with chef solo, specifying a cookbooks path, roles
  # path, and data_bags path (all relative to this Vagrantfile), and adding 
  # some recipes and/or roles.
  #
  # config.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|
  #   chef.cookbooks_path = "../my-recipes/cookbooks"
  #   chef.roles_path = "../my-recipes/roles"
  #   chef.data_bags_path = "../my-recipes/data_bags"
  #   chef.add_recipe "mysql"
  #   chef.add_role "web"
  #
  #   # You may also specify custom JSON attributes:
  #   chef.json = { :mysql_password => "foo" }
  # end

  # Enable provisioning with chef server, specifying the chef server URL,
  # and the path to the validation key (relative to this Vagrantfile).
  #
  # The Opscode Platform uses HTTPS. Substitute your organization for
  # ORGNAME in the URL and validation key.
  #
  # If you have your own Chef Server, use the appropriate URL, which may be
  # HTTP instead of HTTPS depending on your configuration. Also change the
  # validation key to validation.pem.
  #
  # config.vm.provision :chef_client do |chef|
  #   chef.chef_server_url = "https://api.opscode.com/organizations/ORGNAME"
  #   chef.validation_key_path = "ORGNAME-validator.pem"
  # end
  #
  # If you're using the Opscode platform, your validator client is
  # ORGNAME-validator, replacing ORGNAME with your organization name.
  #
  # IF you have your own Chef Server, the default validation client name is
  # chef-validator, unless you changed the configuration.
  #
  #   chef.validation_client_name = "ORGNAME-validator"
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would appear that the issue is the apt-get update note being executed, not sure why this is the case, as my Puppet script appears to be configured correctly to call it...

However - i was able to solve this problem by adding the following line to my Vagrant file:

```
config.vm.provision :shell, :inline => "apt-get update --fix-missing"
```

Would love to know what is wrong with the puppet config though, as it would be nice to be able to avoid having to put this in the Vagrant file.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you made references to some classes which are not included in your post,so I can't comment on those.

It looks like you have a puppet ordering issue; I would suggest running it again and identifying which specific package deployments are failing and determine which class they belong to. So for example if some package x in class y is failing, add the following to your init script just before the closing bracket of the class in question -

```
class y {

    package { "x":

       ensure  => installed,
    }

    Exec["apt-get update"] -> Class["y"]  

}
```

The above will ensure `apt-get update` completes before any class 'y' configuration is run.

Alternatively, for the package resource type, you can continue to add -

require => Exec['apt-get update'] , but I find the class ordering neater.